# Sync using Google calendar APIs Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, calendar, google-api, google-calendar-api

I have iOS calendar app and i need to sync it with google calendar.

I need sync as the following steps:
1-Full sync with google calendar one time only.
2-Incremental sync with google every 1 min.

I read google calendar [documentation](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync#incremental_sync) and google support incremental sync by pass "syncToken" parameter.

The problem:
"syncToken" does NOT available on objective-c library.

Anybody have same issue or ideas what's happening?

Comment: I can help u call me today :P

Answer (score 1):

The GTLQueryCalendar class makes `syncToken` available as a dynamic property:

https://code.google.com/p/google-api-objectivec-client/source/browse/trunk/Source/Services/Calendar/Generated/GTLQueryCalendar.m#49